# Abstract noun as a proper name?

Tags: nouns, proper-nouns, abstract-nouns

This might be silly to ask, and possibly more theoretical than anything else, but it's something I've always pondered.

My first name is Hope. When I was in Elementary School and first learned about abstract nouns, I fell in love with the idea of having such a name - it feels almost magical to me. However sometimes I wonder, does my abstract name technically become a proper noun because it's my name? Or am I still allowed to keep some of that magic and call it an abstract noun?

Thank you!

Comment: Your name is a proper noun, because with other nouns, you can do things like `the X (the hope)`, whereas with your name, `*the Hope` doesn't quite work. That's not to say your name isn't special, and it's semantically still abstract, but syntactically, it's definitely a proper noun.

Comment: That is exactly the sort of explanation I needed. Thank you so much!

Comment: In many instances, names are chosen on the basis of the meaning associated with them: Peace, Faith, Margaret (= Child of light in Persian) ... There may be associations that are more arbitrary. I'm afraid I usually think of one of my favourite comedians when I hear 'Hope' used as a name: 'All words are infinitely polysemous,' as I think Phil White [Wordwizard] said. Mind you, there are also names to avoid. Mr and Mrs Dwyer perhaps shouldn't name their daughter 'Barbara'.

Comment: I have a suggestion.  Obviously, your name is a Proper Noun; however, if it is that important to you, I suggest that you create a pun that uses your name as an abstract noun for the people you meet/know:  "I am here to give Hope." "Hope is all I am, and Hope is all I have."

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that the status and properties of the word clearly differ according to the context. Your name is *Hope* rather than *the Hope* or *a Hope*, whereas the abstract noun *hope* from which it is derived behaves like any other abstract noun. But that much must already be obvious to you, so I'm not sure what else you want to know.